# Get value from a json object after appending with dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

If I have following JSON object:

```
let jsonObject = {a: {b: "c"}};
```

and `if x = "a",`

I know I can do

```
console.log(jsonObject[x]) // which prints {b: "c"}
```

But if I have x = "a.b",

How can I do equivalent of `console.log(jsonObject.a.b) // prints "c";`

I tried doing `console.log(jsonObject[x])` , which obviously will not work.

Is there a way where I can achieve this. 
I hope my question is clear, if not please let me know, I will try to repharse that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split your properties by `.` and then using `reduce` function iterate over the object and get properties one by one. After the function you will get the last one in the returned value. How deep you want, you can use it.

```js
const jsonObject = {a: {b: 'c'}};
const x = 'a.b';
const properties = x.split('.');

const item = properties.reduce((obj, prop) => obj[prop], jsonObject);

console.log(item);
```

Comment: Related to his case, how he need to catch it

Comment: can anyone please give me the non es6 version of above code.. my framework doesn't support above syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the propert accessor using `split(".")` which will give you array of two properties. You can use them to access the property.

You can also loop across this array for accessing the value dynamically.

```js
let jsonObject = {a: {b: "c"}};
var x = "a.b";
var props = x.split(".");
var c = jsonObject[props[0]][props[1]];
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this limited requirement, you can a small function using `reduce`

```
var fnGet = ( obj, x ) => x.split( "." ).reduce( ( a, c ) => a[c] , obj );
```

And then invoke it as

```
try
{
   console.log( fnGet( jsonObject, x ) ); 
}
catch(e)
{
   console.error( "invalid property or object" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
var jsonObject = {a: {b: "c"}};
var x = "a.b";
var val = x.split('.').reduce((m, o) => m && m[o], jsonObject);
console.log(val);
```

The shorthand `if` `m && m[o]` is here to prevent `Cannot read property 'x' of undefined` error for instance in cas `x = "a.d.c";`